# change menu login with logout laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i using laravel 5.2, I want to change the menu login to logout when user login but 
but the result is as shown below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLBIy.png)

this is my code

```
<div id="headerweb">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="/" class="mainlogo" target="_self"><img src="<?=asset('public/images/mainlogo.png')?>" alt=""/></a>
        <div class="mainmenu">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="carakerja" target="_self">CARA KERJA</a> </li>
                <li><a href="order/pemeriksaan" target="_self">ORDER TES LAB</a> </li>
                <li><a href="hasil" target="_self">HASIL LAB ONLINE</a> </li>
                <li><a href="lokasilab" target="_self">LOKASI LAB</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">BLOG</a> </li>
                @if (Auth::guest())
                <li><a href="login" target="_self">LOGIN</a> </li>
                @else
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    @endif
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- endheaderweb -->
```

any one help me??

Comment: change file name filename.blade.php, This is not accepting your blade syntax

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I have to add, but just the same

Comment: I 've changed , but just the same @Jitendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, ensure that you've closed the `@if` statement and the `#headerweb` div.

```
<div id="headerweb">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="/" class="mainlogo" target="_self"><img src="<?=asset('public/images/mainlogo.png')?>" alt=""/></a>
        <div class="mainmenu">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="carakerja" target="_self">CARA KERJA</a></li>
                <li><a href="order/pemeriksaan" target="_self">ORDER TES LAB</a></li>
                <li><a href="hasil" target="_self">HASIL LAB ONLINE</a></li>
                <li><a href="lokasilab" target="_self">LOKASI LAB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                @if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="login" target="_self">LOGIN</a></li>
                @else
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                @endif
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, please move your welcome route from the `routes.php` file to inside the web middleware and that should change the login to logout and display the user name when logged in.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```